# Is there a more efficient way to get arbitrary numbers of threads from Gmail with GmailApp.search()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a large number of emails from a specific label in my Gmail and put them in a Google Drive document. How can I use GmailApp.search() to get the messages without missing any of them?

I tried simply using the non-range-defined GmailApp.search(). According to logs, it only returned 500 emails, while I have approximately 2000 in this label. The problem is that if there aren't 500 (or whatever number) more emails available, GmailApp.search() returns a blank array instead.

Say I have 600 emails, but don't know the exact number. 
I can return the first 500 using GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 500), but then the second search of 500 will return a blank array because only 100 emails remain. How can I get these remaining 100 in this scenario? Is stepping through the threads one at a time, as described in the code below, really the best solution if I want every single email?

```js
for(var i = 0; i < ; i++) {
    //get a single thread 
    var thread = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, i, 1);
    //...
  }
```

I want to output all of the emails, but what happens with GmailApp.search(searchQuery) with no specified range is that 500 emails are returned (at least according to Logger - I have it log a line after every email and it only gets up to 499, starting on 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### More efficient than `var thread = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, i, 1);` is to estimate how many emails you maximally expect (e.g. 2000) and run search query 2000/500 times:

```
var threadArray=[];
    for(var j = 0; j <3 ; j++){    
    var thread = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, j*500, 500);
    thread.forEach(function(e){threadArray.push(e.getId());})
    //now you have an array containing the Ids of all queried emails 
  }
```

This will only append to your array the found elements and no blank entries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getAllThreads(qry) {
  var qry=qry || 'label:qs-financial-institutions-wfb';
  var threads=GmailApp.search(qry);
  var html="";
  for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s -Thread Id:%s First Subject: %s Message Count: %s',i+1,threads[i].getId(),threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject(),threads[i].getMessageCount());
    //You can put another loop in here to get all of the messages
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(1200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Threads");
}
```